# Rephrase sentence to remove "with"

Tags: prepositions

I am trying to rephrase the following sentence to remove the "with" at the end but I am unable to find a way. Can someone please help me out?

Thanks

Sentence: The poet uses the king to portray ideals which he agrees with.

Answer (score 1):

`The poet uses the king to portray ideals that the poet also believes.`

This is the sentence you want, but I'd use a sentence like this if this is a literature class.

```
The poet uses the king as a mouthpiece to express his own ideals.
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the "with" entirely:

> The poet uses the king to portray his own ideals.
> The poet expresses his own ideals through the king.

(That's assuming the "king" is a personage created by the poet.)

If you just want to move the "with" away from the end, you could say this:

> The poet uses the king to portray ideals with which he agrees.

But it sounds better at the end.